# back and forward edges in directed graph

Tags: c++

I am new to graph theory. I am writing a code to find all forward and back edges in directed graph. I searched and implemented the code as below.
My code is going into infinite loop.
Could you please have a look. We will very greateful to you.

```
void dfsVisit(u)
      {
        u->color="gray";
        u->time=count;
        count++;
        for(every child node v of u)
        {
           if(v->color == "black")
           {
              if(u->time < v->time)
                  cout<<"Edge "<<u<<"->"<<v<<" is forward edge"<<endl;
              else
                  cout<<"Edge "<<u<<"->"<<v<<" is cross edge"<<endl;
            }
            if(v->color == "gray")
                 cout<<"Edge "<<u<<"->"<<v<<" is back edge"<<endl;
           if(v->color == "white")
                 cout<<"Edge "<<u<<"->"<<v<<" is tree edge"<<endl;
          dfsVisit(v); 
         }
         u->color="black";
         u->time=count;
         count++;
    }
```

Comment: You have to member the visited edges somehow. Take an example of a cycle of two nodes. The first is visited, it descends "down" to the second, then goes back to the first, which then visits the second again.

Comment: yes you are right. I have marked the node visited. Now only problem I have right now is between cross edges and forward edges. I think there is some issue in logic while marking node as black.

Comment: What does `for(every child node v of u)` mean? Post your full code.

Comment: that means for all the children of node u. v is being used to refer a child of u.

Comment: That `for(every child node v of u)` is not c++ code in any means. Is it edited? Or is it like this in the original source?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems with your code:

1. you call `dfsVisit` for every child, regardless of its color. You indented it into a deeper level, but you didn't add any parenthesis around the white if - based on this pseudocode, only the `cout` is affected by the if statement. 
   But since this is just a pseudocode, you should post the original C++ code you wrote to be clear.
2. you have three colors in your conditions (grey, black, and white), but you never set white anywhere. Your edges are initialized to white before you call `dfsVisit`? (you should consider using an enum or enum class for the colors, it's cleanear and you'll less likely to cause bugs with typos)

Comment: Here is original c++ code. I have initialize vertices with white color before dsfVisit function.

Comment: if this is the original code (except the for loop, that's not C++ there), you should surround your third if with { } (see my first comment)