# Forward edges in a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I am trying to find out all forward and back edges in a graph G. I used to pseudo code provided at: [back and forward edges in directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688752/back-and-forward-edges-in-directed-graph). Which is as below:

DFS-Visit(u)         ▷ with edge classification. G must be a directed graph

```
1.        color[u] ← GRAY
2.        time ← time + 1
3.        d[u] ← time
4.        for each vertex v adjacent to u
5.            do if color[v] ← BLACK
6.                then if d[u] < d[v]
7.                            then Classify (u, v) as a forward edge
8.                            else Classify (u, v) as a cross edge
9.                        if color[v] ← GRAY
10.                            then Classify (u, v) as a back edge
11.                       if color[v] ← WHITE
12.                            then π[v] ← u
13.                                 Classify (u, v) as a tree edge
14.                                 DFS-Visit(v)
15.        color[u] ← BLACK
16.        time ← time + 1
17.        f[u] ← time
```

As per the algorithm if my node is of black color and d[u] < d[v] it is a forward edge.

[image: Graph With forward edges]

Now If we look clearly in above graph edge 0 -> 3 is a forward edge. So, my requirement is to find all forward edges in a graph. I used the above pseudo code but it confuses itself with forward and cross edges. I have written my c++ code shown below based on above pseudo code. Could you please let me know where I am wrong.

Please help me. I have spent a lot of time to find forward edges and nothing is working for me.

Below is my code:

```
// Note  that all nodes has already been marked with white color 
dfsVisit(LinkedList* vertex, int count)
{
    if(!vertex->visited)
    {
        vertex->color="gray";
        vertex->times=count;
        count++;
        for(map<LinkedList*, string>::iterator ad=vertex->childaddr.begin(); ad!=vertex->childaddr.end(); ad++)
        {
            if(ad->first->color == "black")
            {
                if(vertex->times < ad->first->times)
                    cout<<vertex->times<<" "<<ad->first->times<<": "<<"Edge "<<vertex->node<<"->"<<ad->first->node<<" is forward edge"<<endl;
                else
                    cout<<vertex->times<<" "<<ad->first->times<<": "<<"Edge "<<vertex->node<<"->"<<ad->first->node<<" is cross edge"<<endl;
            }
            if(ad->first->color == "gray")
            {
                cout<<vertex->times<<" "<<ad->first->times<<": "<<"Edge "<<vertex->node<<"->"<<ad->first->node<<" is back edge"<<endl;
            }
            if(ad->first->color == "white")
                cout<<vertex->times<<" "<<ad->first->times<<": "<<"Edge "<<vertex->node<<"->"<<ad->first->node<<" is tree edge"<<endl;
            vertex->visited=true;
            dfsVisit(ad->first, count); 

        }
        vertex->color="black";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for help classifying forward edges, when you don't even know what forward edges are?

Comment: I know edge 1 -> 3 , 3 -> 6 are forward edges, But my concern is ahy the algorithm given above classify 2 -> 6 as a forward edge it should be cross edge.

Comment: You say _"Could you please expalin here what edges are forward edges"_. If you know which edges are forward, please state that in your question, and explain what result you require.

Comment: Forward edge is an edge between two nodes which are reachable to each other from by some other path. For example: edge 1 -> 3 is a forward edge because 3 is already reachable from 1 by path 0 -> 1 -> 3. So, my requirement is to find all forward edges in a graph. Where as the psuedo code given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688752/back-and-forward-edges-in-directed-graph classify the cross edges as forward edges. If you could please help here.

Comment: I'm telling you to edit that into your question, replacing the quoted claim that you _don't_ know what forward edges are. If you want help, you should say clearly what result you expected as well as the result you got.